# Why my React native app is too slow when navigation between tabs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

my react native app is too slow when navigating between tabs.Not only tabs. when i clicksome card. it aslo too slow to navigate other screens. why?

This is video of this issue.https://jumpshare.com/s/i1i4kJ1XwR6gMN6B4PYe

it is too much slow in old android phones. How can i fix this. im using react navigation and axios with redux.

this is code one of my screen code

```
import React, { FC, useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react"
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite"
import { Alert, FlatList, StyleSheet, ViewStyle } from "react-native"
import { NativeStackScreenProps } from "@react-navigation/native-stack"
import { AppStackScreenProps } from "app/navigators"
import { Header, Icon, Screen, TextField, Toggle } from "app/components"
import { colors } from "app/theme"
import {
  Box,
  Heading,
  Text,
  ScrollView,
  NativeBaseProvider,
  Button,
  Skeleton,
  Center,
  VStack,
  View,
} from "native-base"
import moment from "moment"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { fetchData } from "./actions"
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native"
import SkeletonView from "app/components/Skeleton"
import { useFocusEffect, useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native"
import LoadingSpinner from "app/components/loading"
import { filterAllJobs, filterJobsByStatus } from "app/utils/sqli"
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo"
import Style from "../../global-styles"
import StatusButton from "app/components/StatusButton"

interface Jobs {
  work_orders: {
    _id: string
    dateCreated: string
    status: string
    siteDetails: {
      name: string
      addressLine1: string
      city: string
      country: string
    }[]
  }
}

interface Jobs1 {
  _id: string
  id: string
  title: string
  status: string
  dateCreated: string
  siteDetails: {
    name: string
    addressLine1: string
    city: string
    country: string
  }[]
}

interface JobScreenProps extends NativeStackScreenProps<AppStackScreenProps<"JobScreen">> {
  navigation: any
  dataCompleted: any
  onGetJobList: any
  loading: boolean
}

export const JobCompletedScreen: FC<JobScreenProps> = observer(function JobScreen({
  navigation,
  dataCompleted,
  onGetJobList,
  loading,
}: JobScreenProps) {
  // Pull in one of our MST stores
  // const { someStore, anotherStore } = useStores()
  // Pull in navigation via hook
  // const navigation = useNavigation()
  const isTabFocused = useIsFocused() // Get the focus state of the tab screen
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState<Jobs[]>([])
  const [jobOffline, setJobOffline] = React.useState<any[]>([])
  const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(false)

  const checkInternetConnectivity = async () => {
    const state = await NetInfo.fetch()
    setIsConnected(state.isConnected)
    return state.isConnected
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const getJobs = async () => {
      if (await checkInternetConnectivity()) {
        onGetJobList()
      } else {
        filterJobsByStatus("Completed").then(setJobOffline).catch(console.error)
      }
    }

    getJobs()
  }, [isConnected, isTabFocused])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (dataCompleted) {
      setJobs(dataCompleted)
    }
  }, [dataCompleted])

  const handleJobPress = useCallback(
    (job: Jobs) => {
      loading = true
      navigation.navigate("JobDetailsScreen", {
        id: job.work_orders._id,
        status: job.work_orders.status,
      })
    },
    [navigation],
  )

  const handleJobPressOffline = useCallback(
    (job: Jobs1) => {
      loading = true
      navigation.navigate("JobDetailsScreen", {
        id: job.id,
        status: job.status,
      })
    },
    [navigation],
  )

  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <>
        {loading == true ? (
          <View>
            <LoadingSpinner />
            <SkeletonView />
          </View>
        ) : null}
        {isConnected ? (
          <FlatList
            data={jobs}
            renderItem={({ item: job, index }) => (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleJobPress(job)}>
                <Box p={5} width={"100%"} borderBottomWidth={0} style={styles.cardStyle}>
                  <Box
                    p={1}
                    width={"100%"}
                    borderWidth={0}
                    flexDirection="row"
                    justifyContent="space-between"
                  >
                    <Text fontSize={20} style={styles.font}>
                      {"#" + job.work_orders._id}
                    </Text>
                    <Text textAlign="right" style={styles.fontNomal}>
                      {moment(job.work_orders.dateCreated, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss[Z]").format(
                        "MMM/DD/YYYY",
                      )}
                    </Text>
                  </Box>
                  <Box
                    p={1}
                    width={"100%"}
                    borderWidth={0}
                    flexDirection="row"
                    justifyContent="space-between"
                  >
                    <StatusButton
                      title="Completed"
                      buttonColor="green"
                      textColor="white"
                      style={{ borderRadius: 30 }}
                    />
                  </Box>

                  <Box p={2}>
                    <Text style={styles.fontNomal}>
                      {job.work_orders.siteDetails && job.work_orders.siteDetails.length > 0
                        ? job.work_orders.siteDetails[0].name
                          ? job.work_orders.siteDetails[0].name
                          : "-"
                        : "-"}
                    </Text>
                  </Box>
                  <Box
                    p={1}
                    width={"100%"}
                    borderWidth={0}
                    flexDirection="row"
                    justifyContent="space-between"
                  >
                    <Text style={styles.fontNomal}>
                      {job.work_orders.siteDetails
                        ? job.work_orders.siteDetails.length > 0
                          ? job.work_orders.siteDetails[0].addressLine1 +
                            ", " +
                            job.work_orders.siteDetails[0].city +
                            ", " +
                            job.work_orders.siteDetails[0].country
                          : "-"
                        : "-"}
                    </Text>
                  </Box>
                </Box>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            ListEmptyComponent={() => (
              <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.fontNoData}>No jobs available</Text>
              </View>
            )}
          />
        ) : (
          <ScrollView>
            {jobOffline && jobOffline.length > 0 ? (
              jobOffline.map((jobs: Jobs1, index: number) => (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleJobPressOffline(jobs)} key={index}>
                  <Box p={5} width={"100%"} borderBottomWidth={0} style={styles.cardStyle}>
                    <Box
                      p={1}
                      width={"100%"}
                      borderWidth={0}
                      flexDirection="row"
                      justifyContent="space-between"
                    >
                      <Text fontSize={15} style={styles.font}>
                        {"#" + jobOffline[index].id}
                      </Text>
                      <Text textAlign="right" style={styles.fontNomal}>
                        {moment(jobOffline[index].dateCreated, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss[Z]").format(
                          "MMM/DD/YYYY",
                        )}
                      </Text>
                    </Box>
                    <Box
                      p={1}
                      width={"100%"}
                      borderWidth={0}
                      flexDirection="row"
                      justifyContent="space-between"
                    >
                      <StatusButton
                        title="Completed"
                        buttonColor="green"
                        textColor="white"
                        style={{ borderRadius: 30 }}
                      />
                    </Box>
                    <Box p={2}>
                      <Text style={styles.fontNomal}>
                        {jobOffline[index] && jobOffline[index].siteName
                          ? jobOffline[index].siteName
                          : "-"}
                      </Text>
                    </Box>
                    <Box
                      p={1}
                      width={"100%"}
                      borderWidth={0}
                      flexDirection="row"
                      justifyContent="space-between"
                    >
                      <Text style={styles.fontNomal}>
                        {jobOffline[index].addressLine1 +
                          +", " +
                          jobOffline[index].city +
                          ", " +
                          jobOffline[index].country}
                      </Text>
                    </Box>
                  </Box>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              ))
            ) : (
              <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.fontNoData}>No jobs available</Text>
              </View>
            )}
          </ScrollView>
        )}
      </>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  )
})

const $root: ViewStyle = {
  flex: 1,
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  font: {
    fontFamily: "Montserrat-Bold",
    color: "#1E1E1E",
  },
  fontNomal: {
    fontFamily: "Montserrat-Regular",
    color: "#1E1E1E",
  },
  fontNoData: {
    fontFamily: "Montserrat-Bold",
    color: "#1E1E1E",
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  container: {
    marginTop: "50%",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  cardStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    marginTop: 10,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10, // Adjust as needed
    width: "auto", // Adjusted width
    marginBottom: 10, // Add margin bottom if needed
    borderRadius: 8, // Adjust as needed
    elevation: 5, // For Android shadow
    shadowColor: "#000", // For iOS shadow
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.3,
    shadowRadius: 4,
  },
})

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
  dataCompleted: state.jobListCompletedReducer.dataCompleted,
  loading: state.jobListCompletedReducer.loading,
  error: state.jobListCompletedReducer.error,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
  onGetJobList: () => dispatch(fetchData()),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(JobCompletedScreen)
```